# Auto creating properties from a collection

Tags: c#

The project I'm working on pulls lots of data from back-end sources into various collections (dictionaries, observablecollections, etc). To make this data more accessible, we expose these collection items as properties.

This creates lots of boilerplate code to map these properties to their backend fields. I've looked at AutoMapper, which seems like it could be part of the solution... but it sounds like it would still require manually creating the list of properties.

What I would ideally want would be a generic way to expose collection items as properties. (All the collection items are strongly typed, and have as their key what the name of the property would need to be).

Thanks for your help.

Update: For those looking for an eexample of code:

```
Dictionary<string,Foo> myDictionary;
myDictionary.Add("MyPropertyName",new Foo());
```

I want to essentially do:

```
 myDictionary.MyPropertyName
```

to access the corresponding value in the dictionary.

Comment: You might be able to use reflection, see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you may want to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Just to be sure I follow - you know the set of keys at design time and want to expose the associated items as strong-typed, design time properties?

Comment: Can you please post some code

Comment: Have you consider using an ORM, such as the well supported Entity Framework?

Comment: I would have loved to use something like EF, but that's not my call :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having individual properties, it makes more sense to use an indexable property with a string for the name of each property, and internally the class will map the string to some backend source.

Typically you would derive your type from `DynamicObject`, which provides the template for this behavior.

In the upcoming version of C# (You can get the preview version or source code for Roslyn), they have introduced new syntax to enable "dynamic" property lookup, using the syntax `x.$propertyName`, which will expand to `x["propertyName"]`

Comment: Actually...if that is what you want...consider using T4 code gen.